# Запись и чтение из файла

Tags: java

Не получается чтение из файла в который я записал данные.

```
Java
    package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static class InputFile {

        public String fileName;
        public String name, surname;
        public String age, height;
        public String ves;

        InputFile(String fileName, String name, String surname, String age, String height, String ves) {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.age = age;
            this.height = height;
            this.ves = ves;
        }

        public void inputFiles(InputFile iF) {
            try {
                FileWriter write = new FileWriter("D:\\" + fileName + ".txt", false);
                write.write(name + "\n");
                write.write(surname + "\n");
                write.write(age + "\n");
                write.write(height + "\n");
                write.write(ves + "\n");
                write.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Ошибка ввода инфомации в файл" + e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class funk {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String fileName;
            String name, surname;
            String age;
            String height;
            String ves;
            fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите название вашего файла: ");

            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите ваше имя: ");
            surname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите вашу фамилию: ");
            age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите ваш возраст: ");
            height = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите ваш рост: ");
            ves = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Введите ваш вес: ");

            InputFile iF = new InputFile(fileName, name, surname, age, height, ves);
            iF.inputFiles(iF);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема? делайте. тут не фриланс биржа

Comment: Причём тут фриланс, я сам учусь и решаю самостоятельно задачи. Я позже выложу код который у меня бедный из-за отсутствия знаний. Все что я смог, это записать в файл нужные мне поля.

Comment: Текст который Вы написали говорит - "Вот задача, напишите кто нибудь за меня, пожалуйста". И опять же - это не фриланс биржа. Если вы что-то написали то - выкладывайте сразу и пишите в чем проблема и что не получается, а не выкладывайте только задание.

Comment: Извините, я в дороге был. Сейчас выложу все что смог сделать сам. И если не сложно посоветуйте литературу по изучению Java.

Comment: У вас ошибка какая-то выскакивает или что?

Comment: Добрый день, дело в том, что Вы не описали конкретно проблему, не предоставили достаточно материалов (ошибку ту же), поэтому многие и недовольны, и воспринимают это как отношение "сделайте!", чтобы не наступать на те же грабли советую Вам прочитать мануал как задавать вопросы на оверфлоу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . А также переделать свой текущий вопрос. Желаю Вам удачи в освоении ru.stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для чтения из файла существует несколько классов, рекомендую ознакомиться с RandomAccessFile и FileReader.

Этого уже должно хватить, чтобы нормально работать с файлами.

**Статья про FileReader:** [тык](https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/6.8.php)

**Статья про RandomAcceesFile:** [тык](https://devcolibri.com/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-4-randomaccessfile-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/)